# Current time and modification time of a file

Tags: command-line, files, find

How does the `ctime` and `mtime` differ for a file in `find` command?
For example, will

```
find . -ctime +1
```

and

```
find . -mtime +1
```

give the same result or not?

Answer (score 0):

## ctime

ctime is the inode or file change time. The ctime gets updated when the file attributes are changed, like changing the owner, changing the permission or moving the file to an other filesystem but will also be updated when you modify a file.

## mtime

mtime is the file modify time. The mtime gets updated when you modify a file. Whenever you update content of a file or save a file the mtime gets updated.
Most of the times ctime and mtime will be the same, unless only the file attributes are updated. In that case only the ctime gets updated

Comment: So, If i want to find files older than one day , I can use both -ctime +1 and -mtime +1", provided attributes never change?

Comment: If by "older than one day" you mean modified more than a day ago, then yes (with your assumption) however linux doesn't support file creation date (last time I checked) so you'll only be able to find by the modified date